# How to use callback functions in outlook add-on

Tags: javascript, outlook, callback, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an outlook plugin, for that the very first step is login procedure. Back end functionality for the login call written in laravel.

When I click the login button, it opens the API (get) using the window. open, once the user and password are validated it stores the token to cookies.

Now what I need is, have to store the token in outlook **roaming settings** instead of the token using a callback function. But I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked out [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings) and [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/manage-state-and-settings-outlook)? Could you explain in detail the specific problem you're facing?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT , on clicking login button,a new window will be opened using window.open method .In that new window ,i need to give username and password  ,it will be verified once the verification completed it returns token .I need to pass this token  function(to store in roaming settings so that i can use it later) in my js file.

Comment: You can use [display dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) to enable this functionality. You can pass the token back to the task pane using the `messageParent` API, and store it in roaming settings there.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Thanks mate !